# Ejecutar expresiones lambda a partir de un tipo "desconocido"

Tags: c#, lambda

En un desarrollo que estoy haciendo, creo un tipo de objeto de alguna de mis clases que se encuentran almacenadas en mi librería de la siguiente forma:

```
  var type = GetTypeFromAssembly(typeName, fullNameSpaceType);
        var instanceOfMyType = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        ReadObject(instanceOfMyType.GetType().GetProperties(), instanceOfMyType, fullNameSpaceType);
        return instanceOfMyType;
```

Luego usando Entity Framework requiero de obtener por ID los valores que pertenecen a dicho objeto instanciando de la forma mencionada anteriormente y para que sea dinámico lo hago de la siguiente forma:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TObject));

        var condition =
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TObject, bool>>(
                Expression.Equal(
                    Expression.Property(parameter, theEntity.GetType().GetProperty("Id").Name),
                    Expression.Constant(id, typeof(TKey))
                    ), parameter
                ).Compile();

        var theObject = _unitOfWork.Set<TObject>().Where(condition).FirstOrDefault();
```

La cuestión es que mi **TObject** es del tipo del objeto que instancié dinamicamente entonces al tratar de ejecutar la expresión no ejecuta correctamente el proceso y manda el siguiente error:

> La propiedad de instancia 'Id' no se ha definido para el tipo 'System.Object'

Lo cual es verdad ya que estoy mandando el tipo **object** y requiero es mandar el tipo de la instancia de mi objeto hecha en reflection, es decir:

```
var theObject = _catalogService.CreateObjectInstance(catalog, "Cms.Spv.Entities");
        _catalogService.GetObjectById<Guid, theObject>(id, theObject);
```

Alguna forma de poder realizar esto ??

Comment: Pregunta interesante. Para ayudarte mejor, sería muy útil que modifiques el código en tu pregunta de modo que realmente sea [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Desconozco la primera parte del código, pero si ya estas hablando de Entity Framework, una forma fácil de obtener un elemento en base a su contexto apartir de su Id es de la siguiente manera.

```
var MiObjeto = context.Set<T>().Find(PK);
```

Donde T es el tipo de dato de la entidad y PK es el Id.

Por otra parte hacer expresiones apartir de un tipo desconocido hasta ahora no he podido :(

Pero lo pude resolver utilizando una clase generica

```
public abstract class MiClaseGenerica<T> : IMiClaseGenerica<T> where T : class
{
    public T ObtenerPorId(long PK)
    {
        return context.Set<T>().Find(PK);
    }
}

public interface IMiClaseGenerica<T> : IDisposable where T : class
{
    T ObtenerPorId(long PK);
}
```

Otra manera en que creo que se puede resolver esto es utilizar como tipo una interface comun para las etidades.

```
return _unitOfWork.Set<IComun>().Where(x=> x.PropiedadComun==id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Saludos

Comment: +1 'Inface comun para las entidades'. Tampoco se me ocurre otra manera .